# hierarchically adding different library paths to rpath in cmake

Tags: gcc, cmake

I have a project where two different packages (gtkmm and matlab engine) rely on different incompatible versions of the same library (libfreetype). I was told by mathworks to solve the problem in gcc with the line:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64
```

This works well in the gcc command line. How can I translate this into cmake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a linker flag, so you probably want to do something like

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -Wl,-rpath,....)
```